# Adding a QMainWindow or Widget to another Widget - access to members

Tags: c++, qt

Let's assume I want to create a widget that has a blurry shadow around it, and I want to make it this way:

1. class A: contains an empty layout and some margin around it for the shadow. It is transparent
2. class B: contains my widget or mainWindow with all its members, functions etc.
3. I add a widget object `objB`  of class B to an object `objA` of class A (add it to its layout).

Both forms are created in an `ui`-file. The functionality of `objB` e.g. is implemented in `classB.cpp` and `classB.h`.

Now what I am wondering:

Normally, if I want to keep `objB` alive after its constructor, I add a pointer to a list of my main class. But now, do I have to save a pointer of `objB` or `objA`? And how do I access the members of this widget now? Are they now members of `objA`?

And does it make a difference whether my `objB` is of type `QMainWindow`or `QWidget`?

Comment: You can't add `QMainWindow` to another widget because `QMainWindow` is always a top-level widget. It's reasonable to keep pointer to the top-level widget (`objA`) and access `objB` through its getter. If you add a widget to `A` form in Designer and promote it to class `B`, then `objB` will be the part of the `A`'s ui class (something like `ui->objB`). If you add it manually in `A`'s code, you should save a pointer to `objB` as a field of `A` class and provide a getter to access it from outside.

Comment: Yes you can: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/21548 
Download the zipfile and take a look at the ui-files.
That is what I want to adapt my program to. To create a blurry shadow. But did not succeed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt manages most of this using it's object trees.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/objecttrees.html

Basically, you can just associate anything to it's parent and you don't need to make it a member variable.  If you look through the examples, there are a number of them that have a just a main.cpp, and doesn't even make a separate class to keep track of what belongs to what.

EDIT: Almost any GUI element that you put on the object tree should be a pointer, and initialized on the heap with `new`.  If you don't do that they you can run into problems later, when things go out of scope.

You can even find elements on the object tree if you name objects and use the `QObject::findChild<T>(QString name);` function.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild

The main difference between `QMainWindow` and `QWidget` is that `QMainWindow` comes with a menubar, toolbars, docks, and a central widget pointer set up for you.

If you don't use any of the menubar, toolbars, docks, etc, the functionality and look and feel of a `QMainWindow` compared to a `QWidget` is almost identical.

The only difference is how to start adding elements to the middle of your widget.  With `QMainWindow` you set any sort of `QWidget` as the central widget and go from there.  For `QWidget`, usually I set a layout in it, and then hang things in the layout, but you can just start parenting things to it, too.

Also like Pavel Strakhov said, the `QMainWindow` must be parentless on the object tree.

Also in general, I find it easier to manage and work on large projects without using Qt Designer, and the ui generation.  Most of the examples don't use the generated `ui` stuff, too.

On a side note, there is also a big push to start using QML and QtQuick for GUI's, but the QWidget functionality isn't going away anytime soon.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have downloaded the zipfile from here http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/21548, loaded the project in QtCreator and took a look at it. The author is adding the `QMainWindow` content into a layout of the blurry background window that is a `QWidget`. Till now I only reached of partial understanding on what he does

Comment: So does my answer make it more clear why coding like that in Qt works?